# How do I rename a GitHub repository via their API?

Tags: git, github-api

Looking at the GitHub API reference at http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html, I see all sorts of good stuff, but I don't see any way to rename a repository through the API. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create some variables for clarity:

```
user=MyUserName
pass=MyPassword
newName='{"name": "NewNameForRepo"}'
oldName="MyRepo"
```

Then use curl to make the request:

```
curl -u "$user:$pass" -X PATCH -d "$newName" https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$oldName
```

Comment: I've confirmed that this works. I used OAuth2 token instead of `user:pass`.

Comment: More clarity: [`-X`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502004/1705829) is used to specify another request method besides PUT, GET,HEAD and POST, `patch` is used to modify a resource on the server partially. `-d` is for `POST`ing a key-value pair, see my link on the X flag.

Comment: Adding to @PaulAnnesley comment, you can do: `curl -u "$user:$token..` instead of `curl -u $user:$pw..`

Answer (score 4):

This is possible through the [Edit Repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit) GitHub API method, but here's the simplest example to do this with `curl`:

```
curl \
 -H "Authorization: Token [token]" \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -X PATCH \
 --data '{ "name": "new-repo-name" }' \
 https://api.github.com/repos/owner/old-repo-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional notes to what [braitsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228315/braitsch) said already,

If you are trying to rename a repository under an **organization**, add these variables:

```
myToken='XXXX_Your_Personal_Access_Token_XXXX'
myOrg="MyGithubOrg"
newName='{"name": "NewNameForRepo"}'
oldName="MyRepo"
```

And, make a curl request like this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token $myToken' -X PATCH -d "$newName" https://api.github.com/repos/$myOrg/$oldName
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're using GitHub CLI:

```
gh alias set repo-rename 'api -X PATCH "repos/$1" -f name="$2"'

gh repo-rename username/oldreponame newreponame
```

Answer (score -3):

Create a new repo, push to it and delete the old one ?

Comment: Or fork/delete through their API.

Comment: The create/push/delete solution kind of works, but the new repo would contain whatever I pushed from my local copy of the repo, so it wouldn't necessarily be a perfect copy of the old GitHub repo. Also, wouldn't I lose issues and wiki and stuff if I did that?

Comment: Yes, you would lose issues and wiki. Maybe you want to ask Guthub's support team?