# How to rename a GitHub hosted repository?

Tags: github

I recently participated in the San Francisco Drone Olympics.  After a friendly note from the real Olympics, the name was changed to the Drone Games or somesuch.  I need to change my GitHub name accordingly.

So, **How does one rename a repository on GitHub?**

For concreteness, I would like to rename

- https://github.com/marhar/droneolympics

to

- https://github.com/marhar/ArctiNode

Note: this question deals with the followup to doing so, but not the procedure to change the name.

[How do I rename a repository on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751585/change-repo-name-in-github)

Comment: Your repo -> Admin -> Rename -> type in new name -> Confirm -> Kaboom!

Comment: sweet, thanks! add it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On GitHub, go to your repo, Admin, Rename. Specify the new name, then Change, Confirm and that will be done.

You should also rename the remote origin in all local copies of your repo in order pushing and pulling to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your Github repository, click Settings.
2. Go to General/Repository name(It's at the very top).
3. Edit your repository name and click Rename.