# How to change the name of a folder in github

Tags: github

[image]

How do I change the name of that folder? I've tried, but nothing online seems to be working. Is there even any way to change its name?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-in-githubweb

Comment: I've seen that, I don't know how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Github.

000webhost is a much, much better alternative and allows the ability to alter the name of folders.

Comment: You can use the webhost to completely manage your website. It's a lot simpler and user friendly than git hub, rendering github completely useless. My hope was that if anyone ever came across this thread, they would stop wasting their time on github and use the (better) alternative.

Comment: I don't think it's suitable for any kind of project tbh

Answer (score 0):

As someone already answered this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-on-github-website)

If you want a better interface (Vscode). you can try online version vscode hosted by official Github.

Open the repo in Github and press `.` that will redirect you from `github.com` to `github.dev`

If this is your first time Install and accept if you agree with the terms,
Now you can just Vscode,

- Right side, you will see the `Explorer` (file-tree).
- Go to the folder, right-click and select rename and enter a new name
- Once renamed, open `Source Control` (Third Icon or press `control + shift + g`)
- Enter the commit message and press `command + enter`

That's it.