# How to change a folder name in github

Tags: git, github

I just made a new repository with a single folder, that contains various subfolders and files inside it. I want to change the name of the "F2F" folder. I know it is possible using command line, but wanted to ask whether there is a GUI alternative to the same(on web).[image]

Also, I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-in-githubweb/32620165) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183788/in-a-git-repository-how-to-properly-rename-a-directory), and they don't help.

Comment: Nope it's an old blog @Sid

Answer (score 23):

Just simply go to the reop on your web browser and change the URL to ".dev"
example: change github.com/{github username}/{reponame}
to: github.dev/{github username}/{reponame}

Comment: Phenomenal response. I had no idea this was an option. Thank you.

Comment: Internet manages to amaze me every day!!

Comment: whoa... that's neat

Comment: awesome! helped me alot!

and yeah I almost forgot to commit and push the changes before going back to github.com/{github username}/{reponame}

Comment: I really don't know this powerful feature exists in github. Thank you!!

Answer (score 9):

**Go to your repo that contains the folder you want to rename.**
**Then, press the “.” key.**
**A web editor will show up. Navigate to the folder, click on it, and press enter.**

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you can't do this in the browser.

Git operates just file, never folder (they are treated as file paths). And you can rename the file to "move" into another directory, in the browser, for all the files in that folder, to "change a folder name". But it seems no batch operations in the browser.

For move a file into another path in the browser: Edit that file, then you can rename the file. In the box of renaming the file, try to input slash `/` or delete at the beginning of the input box.

Answer (score 2):

Open Git Bash.

Change the current working directory to your local repository.

Rename the file, specifying the old file name and the new name you'd like to give the file. This will stage your change for commit.

```
git mv old_filename new_filename
```

[get full description with example on github](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-file-using-the-command-line/)

Comment: I know how to do it using command line. I am asking for a GUI option.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting this error? when rinning git ls_files I see all the contents well. fatal: bad source, source=old_name, destination=old_name/new_name