# Moving an entire **folder** in GitHub

Tags: github, directory, file-move

I'm very well aware of how to create new folders and move single files between folders. Just edit the name and commit the change.

I was wondering if there was an easy or similar way to move an entire folder to a new location within the same repository.

E.g., say I have `myrepo/a/b/c/d/` and `myrepo/a/b/c/e/` (that is, `/d/` and `/e/` are subfolders of `/c/`), how can i move folder `/d/` to be within `/b/` (i.e. on the same tier as `/c/`)?

The end result would be `myrepo/a/b/c/e/` and `myrepo/a/b/d/`.

I'm unfamiliar with the GitHub command line 'thingy' and I would appreciate it if the quick and easy solution didn't use that advanced feature (although I would be glad to learn it).

Don't mark me as a duplicate when I say I have the same question as [How to rename a directory/folder in Github(Web)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-in-githubweb). It is the **very same question**, but **that question hasn't been answered yet either,** or at least the solution isn't clear. Again, I don't need to know how to move a **file.** I want to move an entire **folder**.

Comment: Just move the folder and add+commit the changes.

Comment: "`git-mv` - Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink". It should be as simple as `git mv a/b/c/d a/b/`

Comment: @tkausl The point is, I don't even know how to move the folder itself. All I know is my method of renaming, which only works for files (to my knowledge), not folders.

Comment: @Amadan . How would I access the GitHub command line (or wherever you would type that code)? I'm very new to the system, sorry!

Comment: Dunno. To me, command line is the starting point, I don't do anything to access it. What is your starting point? Windows desktop?

Comment: @Amadan . I access GitHub online, through Google Chrome, on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: GitHub does not have such a capability, AFAIK. Install [git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/); git command line is available inside the git-bash shell it installs. You would need to learn a bit of Git and bash to use it effectively. I don't know whether or not it is available in Git GUI, as I don't use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a directory/folder in Github(Web)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-in-githubweb)