# CSS not being applied on GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I've uploaded my files and the styling isn't appearing and I don't know why it's going wrong.

Here is how my site looks: https://acrt3.github.io/profile/

[Here is the code in my index file linking the stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA38u.png)

[Here is image of my file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv7CP.png)

Comment: You aren't linking to the file correctly. Can you post your file tree?

Comment: You have no file like styles.css exist on your folder. Have you uploaded the file???

Comment: I've uploaded file tree. And my styles.css file is in the css folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css folder is named `CSS` (uppercase). Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
```

Comment: this didn't change anything

Comment: btw, it is a good practice to use lowercase names for folders and files.

Comment: It should fix, I've tried. Just replace your line with this.

Comment: this has worked now, must have took a while to update, thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-on-github-website