# Rename Directory in Repository without having to reupload files

Tags: git, github, mv

I am attempting to rename a directory without reuploading a new directory, due to my directory being very large in size. Is there a way to change the directory name without uploading all my huge files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename a directory/folder on GitHub website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-on-github-website)

Comment: @xtropicalsoothing I tried, it didn't work. I think Github removed the feature

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I went to vscode.dev, opened my repository, and renamed the folder there. No code required.