# Are Git repository names case sensitive?

Tags: git, github

I realize that changing the name of a Git repository is not a trivial task, and I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751585/change-repo-name-in-github) which describes how to change the repository name in the general case (I am also using GitHub).

However, I will only be changing the *case* of the repository name, e.g. `Abc` to `abc`. Therefore, can I simply change the name in the settings page of my repository on GitHub and be all set? Or do I still need to follow the steps outlined in the previous link?

Comment: Yes - the repository names *are* case sensitive.  "abc" != "Abc".  *HOWEVER* DNS names (including the host name part of URLs) *are* case-insensitive (http://GOOGle.CoM == http://google.com).

Comment: @paulsm4: github urls are not case sensitive

Comment: Yes they *can be*.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650488/why-are-github-project-document-page-urls-case-sensitive-what-are-the-negative), [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found) and [here](https://metacpan.org/module/App::GitHub::FindRepository).  And remember: A "url" consists of multiple parts.

Comment: +1 @paulsm4: I take it back - the behavior is not guaranteed and might just be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, I found that you *cannot* simply change the repository name in the settings page. The steps from the link in the body of the question must still be followed. Although in my case it was as simple as:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/newreponame.git
```