# GitHub Fork or rename or create new git?

Tags: git, github, fork, pull-request

I forked someone's project and updated it in some big ways to work for my app. It's now a much more robust little plugin with some major changes to its workflow in general. I'm a GitHub noob at this point, so: Is it a good idea to  try and do a pull request for my large update? Or should I rename the forked repository as my own? Or should I just start from scratch, copy pasting my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you believe that the author could accept your changes and merge them into the project then do a pull request and leave it for him/her to decide.

Comment: If the repo that you forked from contains a license, then you probably need to legally adhere to the terms of that license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2014: If the changes are too important to be easily merged back in the original repo, I would recommend considering your repo as a true fork, and advertise it as the "new improved version".

You can even rename your [GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16602311/6309) to mark that fork.

---

2022: you can [create a fork directly with a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849165/6309)!