# Git/Github, moving and properly updating a repo

Tags: git, github

I moved a git repo from https://github.com/username/testrepo.git to https://github.com/companyname/testrepo.git and now need to do some more work on the gem. When I go into the directory on my local machine and type `git remote -v` it still says origin https://github.com/username/testrepo.git.

My question is, what is the proper way for me to update this remote with the new location and begin working again?

Comment: I removed the `[ruby]` and `[rails]` tags since this has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with Ruby or Rails. It also doesn't have anything to do with GitHub, but I left that tag in for now.

Answer (score 2):

First remove the origin remote:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then rename it like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:companyname/testrepo.git
```

Source: [how to rename a repository on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686588/how-to-rename-a-repository-on-github)

Comment: You do not need o remove old remote. It's enough to change only url of origin.