# Update origin after renaming the repository name

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my project files to my repository. But when I do that I get errors as in following screenshot.

[image: Pushing files]

I had a repository in that project file before and I deleted it. Now I have created another repository with a different name in that project file. But I get these errors now. Please tell me what I should do.

Comment: Remove your current remote and add a new one. Check `git remote` commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github "fatal: remote origin already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To update the origin to the new repository.

`git remote set-url origin <new-url>`

In your case, paste the command below if you updated your remote repo as per name suggested.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/BSThisarasinghe/Sabra-Medical-Center.git
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your remote settings.

First remove the old origin: `git remote remove origin`

Next, add the updated url: `git remote add origin _new url_`

After that, confirm everything looks good with `git remote -v` and you should be able to push again.