# curl -X POST command with RCurl

Tags: r, post, curl, rcurl

I'm trying to get the following HTTP POST containing XML to work using RCurl package in R:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.example.com/resource.xml' -d 'From=value' 
-d 'To=value' -d    'Body=value' -u username:password
```

I have no problems running the above code using command line, but when I try to use postForm in the RCurl package, I run into problems.

Here is my attempt using postForm in RCurl:

```
postForm('https://api.example.com/resource.xml',
userpwd="username:password",From='value',To='value',Body='value')
```

It seems supplying the username/password is the main issue. I can pass the params without an issue.

Comment: Try using the `.opts` argument. It requires a named list (eg: `.opts=list(From="value", To="value")` etc)

Comment: reminder, the -X usage in your command line is superfluous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498371/curl-get-and-xget

Comment: posted my (sad) RCurl attempt.

Comment: I have no trouble passing parameters in the above code. It's only when I need to supply a username:password that I get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the `userpwd` argument incorrectly. Try:

```
postForm('https://api.example.com/resource.xml',
         From='value',
         To='value',
         Body='value',
         .opts=list(userpwd="username:password"))
```

Note: **RCurl** syntax is kind of idiosyncratic, so in `postForm` the `...` argument refers to HTTP headers whereas in `getURL` (from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172624/setting-query-params-to-restful-api-with-geturl-in-rcurl)), the `...` argument refers to curl options. This is probably what is tripping you up.

Comment: Yes, I really find the RCurl syntax to be inconsistent and the documentation to be unclear.