# setting query params to RESTful API with getURL in RCurl

Tags: r, get, rcurl

I would like to translate the following HTTP GET command to work with RCurl:

```
curl -G https://api.example.com/resource \
-d "param=value" \
-d "param=value" \
-u 'user:password'
```

Here is my attempt using getURL in RCurl:

```
getURL("https://api.example.com/resource",
userpwd ="username:password",param="value",param="value")
```

The first code block works fine in my command line terminal and I have no troubles using getURL until I try to set parameters; I get warning messages saying that the params are "Unrecognized CURL options". Any ideas?

Comment: posted my RCurl attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything going to the `...` argument is interpreted as a curl option. You need to put parameters as a list in the `httpheader` argument. [See documentation](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/installed/RCurl/html/getURL.html).

Try something like:

```
getURL("https://api.example.com/resource",
       userpwd ="username:password",
       httpheader=list(param1="value",param2="value"))
```