# How to reject requests with unwanted methods in http?

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm trying to reject any method sent other than POST, GET, PUT, DELETE directly on http.

**Example:** curl "http://192.168.1.99/lispbx/lisintegra.php?gacao=discar&gsrc=1002&gdst=85989297893&gkey=teste@teste" **-X NUNES**

Sending this way it works even if it's not sending a valid method.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: a curl is a get i believe , see this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502004/2757519