# Curl -X in GET and POST request. Do I need -X?

Tags: api, curl

In a project I have seen colleagues setting the -X parameter in a GET CURL request. I admit that I am not an expert and I had always fired my requests without this parameter. And it worked. I know about X that it stands for request. But nothing more.

**Now my question.** Is it necessary to include the X parameter and if so why?

`curl GET http://localhost:3000/api/projects/` instead of
`curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/projects/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl -GET and -X GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498371/curl-get-and-x-get)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**. You normally should not use -X at all with curl. If you want a `GET` request, just specify the URL as GET is the default. If you want POST, you use -d or -F (but no -X) etc.

See https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/

Also related: [curl -GET and -X GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498371/curl-get-and-x-get/8502004#8502004)