# Get GitHubs repository description with (J)Git

Tags: git, github, jgit

In GitHub every repository can have a short description, which is shown under the `Code | Network | Pull Requests | Issues | Wiki | Graphs | Settings` bar.

I can [edit the description on the GitHub webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757751/how-do-you-change-a-repository-description-on-github), but I want to read and change it *with JGit or Git*. Is this possible?

(First I tried to read `.git/description`, but every repository from GitHub just seems o contain the same text:

```
Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.
```

Is `.git/description` used anywhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .git/description has nothing to do with the description field of a GitHub repo.

You can get that field with a simple curl (i.e. nothing to do with `git` either), following the [GitHub API for repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get):

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:reponame  2>/dev/null | grep description

# For instance
curl https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/compileEverything  2>/dev/null | grep description
```

You can edit it easily enough, with a `PATCH` http method:

```
curl -u "$user:$pass" -X PATCH -d '{"name":"$reponame","description":"new_value"}' https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$reponame
```

(same as in "[How do I rename a GitHub repository via their API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603754/6309)")

Comment: Thanks, the GitHub API would be possible to get/edit the description. So the description didn't exist somewhere in the Git repository itself (which I hoped first)?

Comment: @Sonson123 I have added an edit example. But the description isn't part of the git repo.