# What is a simple way to bulk rename GitHub repositories?

Tags: github, rename, bulk

I have a large number of repositories on GitHub which start "hdx-scraper-" eg. "hdx-scraper-fts". I want to rename them all to start "hdx-pipeline-" eg. "hdx-pipeline-fts". I've not found a way to do that en masse in the UI. Is there any utility that offers this feature? If not, please give an example of how to find all the repositories and rename them using the GitHub API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename a GitHub repository via their API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4777535/283366)

Comment: 1. Looks for an API, 2.  Write a script that calls said API. Almost anything in GH is scriptable.

Comment: @Phil that could provide part of the answer. I've added more specifics to the question.